# Show $17$ does not divide $5n^2 + 15$ for any integer $n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Claim: $17$ does not divide $5n^2 + 15$ for any integer $n$.

Is there a way to do this aside from exhaustively considering $n \equiv 0$, $n \equiv 1 , \ldots, n \equiv 16 \pmod{17}$ and showing $5n^2 + 15$ leaves a remainder of anything but $0$. It's easy but tedious. Since if $n \equiv 0$ then $5n^2 + 15 \equiv 15$ so that 17 does not divide $5n^2 + 15$. I did four more cases successfully, got bored, and skipped to the last case which also worked. Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 5):

You can transform the equation a bit.

$5n^2 + 15 \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$ is equivalent to $5n^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{17}$  and further to $n^2 \equiv 14 \pmod{17} $ and finally $n^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{17} $.

This is already more convenient to check. And, if you know about [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) you can finish quite directly by invoking that $-3$ is a quadratic residue only for primes congruent $1 \mod 3$ while $17$ is $2 \mod 3$.

Answer (score 4):

$5(n^2 + 3) \equiv 0 \bmod \ 17$ if and only if $n^2 \equiv 14 \bmod \ 17$ but $\forall\ n \ n^2 \equiv 1, 4, 9, 16, 8, 2, 15, 13\ \bmod \ 17$

Answer (score 3):

${\rm mod}\ 17\!:\ 5(n^2\!+3)\equiv0\,\Rightarrow\,n^2\equiv-3\,\Rightarrow\,n^4\equiv 9\,\Rightarrow\, n^8\equiv -4\,\Rightarrow\,n^{16}\equiv -1$ contra little Fermat

Comment: I think you should consider two cases: 1. 17 divides n. 2. (n,17)=1 for the Fermat's little theorem. Correct?

Comment: @Fermat $\ $ Obviously $\,n^2\equiv -3\,\Rightarrow\, n\not\equiv 0.\ $ But, yes, it does need to be excluded. I leave some details to the OP, e.g. also checking that $5$ can be cancelled because it is coprime to $17$ so invertible (or note $\,7\cdot 5\equiv 1)\ \ $

Comment: Yes. I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ n=17k + p $ where $ p, k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\le p \le 16 $.
Therefore $ 5n^2+15=5 \cdot 17^2 k^2+170pk +5p^2 +15 \equiv 5p^2 -2 \; (mod \; 17)$

PS. You can do it for $n^2 +3$.